MongoDB online archival ObjectId vs datefield
I'm trying to archive data which is older than 4 months in a mongodb collection. There are existing documents in the collection.
As per mongodb, for standard collections we can either use date fields or custom queries. Since _id is by default indexed and contains ObjectId(includes timestamp value), I'm thinking of creating custom query which does $lt operation on the 4 months older ObjectId value:
 {
  "_id": {
    "$lt": ObjectId(Math.floor(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 4) / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000")
  }
}

But, is this the efficient way? Is it better to add new date field in the existing collection documents and then do archival based on it or use _id anyways as this is already indexed to archive the documents?

Your current query doesn't look well to me. It could be vulnerable to errors caused by client side timezone and objectId conversion. You may want to try out solutions in this post. Personally, I would use an extra date field so it can be indexed. Currently, the ObjectId conversion to date does not seem to use index. In addition, if your "archival" involves removing data from the collection, you may find a TTL index useful.

Do you plan to use the Atlas Online Archive? If yes, then you can simply specify the numbers of days, e.g. 120 in your case.

@ray, Since he is calculating the date on the client side, that query would use an index, like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/pdbaheyFX5C

@Joe This makes sense to me if OP must calculate the date on the client side. I just want to remind OP of the caveats. This post looks like an opinion-based / review question to me anyway.

@ray how does ObjectId conversion to date came into picture here? I'm just using sort of range query on _id (ObjectId) to get the documents.
In order to get start ObjectId and end ObjectId, i'm using date to generate that. By default ObjectId field is indexed anyways right

@vinter As Joe has already pointed out, your query should work fine and will leverage the index. What I want to point out is that there could be a potential timezone issue. Say the server is using the UTC timezone and the client side is using PST, there could be a discrepancy in data fetched due to the 7-8 hour timezone difference(though might be relatively insignificant since you are working with 4 months of data). Also, the code is having arguably low readability, but that is just my opinion.

When you have to deal with date/time function, I recommend to use a 3rd party date library, e.g. luxon, Day.js or moment.js.
I would suggest to create a ObjectId, then it will also use the index:
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
ObjectId.fromDate = function(sourceDate) {
   var seconds = Math.floor(sourceDate.getTime() / 1000);
   return ObjectId(seconds.toString(16).padEnd(8, '0') + "0000000000000000");
}

db.collection.find({
    _id: {
      $lt: ObjectId.fromDate(DateTime.now().minus({ months: 4 }).toJSDate())
    }
})

Update
For Online-Archive see Configure Online Archive Through the User Interface at Custom Criteria

In this custom filter example, when the current date exceeds the date
in the bucket_end_date field in the documents, Atlas subtracts thirty
days (specified in milliseconds) from the current date and then
archives data after that many days, hours, and minutes.
{
  "$expr": { "$lte": [
    "$bucket_end_date",
    { "$subtract": [ "$$NOW", 2592000000 ] }
  ] }
}

In this custom filter example, when the current date exceeds the date
inside an objectId, Atlas subtracts thirty days (specified in
milliseconds) from the current date and then archives data after that
many days, hours, and minutes.
{
  "$expr": {
    "$lte": [
      {"$toDate": "$_id"},
      { "$subtract": [ "$$NOW", 2592000000 ] }
    ]
  }
}

If you use $expr in the custom filter, sometimes the Atlas cluster
might be unable to use an index for archiving data.

So, it will work like that, but it may not be the fastest way.

I have to give this as a custom query during mongodb online archival policy, so adding external libraries won't work i guess. I just have to give it a query like how to write in find bar in mongodb compass

Got it, So the better way is to add date field in mongo collections and archive based on that only

Yes, I would suggest to do so.
